# spotting an Ambiguous BNF

Tags: grammar, bnf, ambiguity

I have an assignment to correct an ambiguous BNF, but I am completely lost. I know this not a true programming question, and I will gladly delete it if it is not an appropriate question for these boards. Are there any good sites where I could learn more about BNF's? The one I am dealing with seems rather simple, but I can't find any examples or good explanations regarding BNF's. I have had some experience spotting ambiguous parse trees and other sorts of grammars, but I am completely lost on this one.

Since it is a school assignment, I am not sure I should post the BNF in question, but if anyone knows of a good site that I could look over to perhaps gain a better understanding of how to attack my question. I really just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some BNF describing a context-free grammar is also describing a state machine (in this case a [Pushdown automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton)).  The best way to do this is probably by inspection of the state machine.

As a starting point, you could look into what a [conflict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Conflicts_in_the_constructed_tables) is within [parsers that make use of such automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser).

Comment: Thanks! I will look those pages over. Also, would you mind explaining how literals in BNF work? It seems like they don't really do anything.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  BNF just consists of terminal and non-terminal symbols.  I believe things like having string literals lying around in grammars is just a consequence of nobody being very precise about what constitutes a symbol.  If this is the thing you mean, then the way they work is that they mostly don't.  They tend to be very fragile.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two or more of the same nonterminals at the right side of a sentence it's ambiguous. For example: < expr > -> < expr > + < expr > | < facto >. The right side expr's can be exported in different ways in the tree, so different trees can be drawn and it's ambiguous.